# Unable to run Android Studio x86 or x86_64 emulator on my AMD Athlon II X4 635 Processor

Tags: android, android-emulator

My CPU reports having SSE, SSE2 and SSE4a flags but not SSE3, which Android Studio is demanding for x86 emulation. 64bit emulation complains that SSSE3 SSE4.1 and SSE4.2 are missing.

The ARM emulator has started but is taking forever to boot. I may die before it completes.

What are my options for getting the x86 emulator running? Any?

Martin